# Torch7 Mac Installation error

Tags: python, c, macos, data-analysis

I am trying to install in mac machine Torch7. When I am trying to install torch using this tutorial https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Cheatsheet#installing-and-running-torch on the second line(curl -sk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-luajit+torch | bash)  I am facing the following error:

-- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA - found
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found suitable version "4.7.4", minimum required is
  "4.3.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.12.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1393 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (FIND_PACKAGE)

Have you experienced this problem before? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-all | bash` as advised at https://github.com/torch/ezinstall I got the same error, i.e.

`Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: 
QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found suitable version "4.8.6", minimum required is
  "4.3.0")`

When I ran `which qmake` I found that qmake was located in `~/anaconda/bin/qmake`. I tried a bunch of different things to set the `QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE`, `QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE`, and `QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE` paths correctly e.g.

`qmake -set "QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE" /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/bin/moc
qmake -set "QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE" /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/bin/rcc
qmake -set "QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE" /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/bin/uic`

But nothing worked.

So what I did was remove the anaconda installation via `rm -rf ~/anaconda`

I ran `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/install-all | bash` again, and everything install correctly. Then I just reinstalled anaconda.

That was a relief. It's probably not the best solution, but I hope this can also work for you.

Comment: Removing anaconda is not necessary, removing it from the PATH is enough during the install(e.g., commenting out this line in ~/.bash_profile: export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH").

Comment: you dont have to uninstall or rm anaconda - simply rename the folder, do the torch installation and then rename anaconda folder back to anaconda and ... done!